# Upgrading RAM for HP probook 450 G1 to 32GB

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, hp-pavilion

I constantly see that max ram available for this laptop is 16GB, it has two slots, one slot 8GB.

However, I see a DDR3 module that is 16GB one stick, could I buy two of these and put it in? Processor is i7 4702MQ and I see it supports 32GB RAM and I'm not aware of anything else in the pc ecosystem that could limit RAM besides the CPU and RAM slots in the motherboard.

Should I be worried or I can just buy 32 GB RAM and it will work?

Comment: It is up to 16GB *total memory*. See [RAM & SSD Upgrades | HP - Compaq ProBook 450 G1 | Crucial UK](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP---Compaq/probook-450-g1)

Comment: But what is the reasoning behind it? What happens if I put in 32GB ? Is there any reason it could not work?

Comment: The motherboard does not support it.

Comment: @VanillaFace Your system wouldn’t POST

Answer (score -1):

HP ProBook 450 G1 does not support more than 2 x 8GB.

Manual here: [http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03765776.pdf](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03765776)